# Timeline - Next and Previous Event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a timeline, but I am not able to implement the function when I click on one of the circles the green bar of the event is completed by then or "disabled" if I click on a previous circle,

**My code**

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Harry_x21/pen/NWWoLeR)

**What I tried**

```
  <button id="toggleButton">Toggle</button>


var completes = document.querySelectorAll(".complete");
var toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
function toggleComplete(){
  var lastComplete = completes[completes.length - 1];
  lastComplete.classList.toggle('complete');
}
toggleButton.onclick = toggleComplete;
```

I tried to implement this with a button, but to no avail. The goal now is to click on the circle and complete "the green line" until then ... without the button.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please include what you have tried to the CodePen also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced .status:before with .status .circle and added .circle elements within .status elements.

```js
  var lis = timeline.querySelectorAll('#timeline > li');

  lis.forEach(function(li) {

    var circle = li.querySelector('.status .circle');

    circle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      var i = 0;

      if (!li.classList.contains('complete')) {
        for (i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
          lis[i].classList.add('complete');
          if (lis[i] == li) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i=lis.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          if (lis[i] == li) {
            break;
          }
          lis[i].classList.remove('complete');
        }
      }

    });

  });
```

```css
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.status {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #D6DCE0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.status .circle {
  content: '';                  
  width: 25px;                  
  height: 25px;                 
  background-color: white;      
  border-radius: 25px;          
  border: 1px solid #ddd;       
  position: absolute;           
  top: -15px;                   
  left: 42%;                    
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

/*.status:before {                */
/*  content: '';                  */
/*  width: 25px;                  */
/*  height: 25px;                 */
/*  background-color: white;      */
/*  border-radius: 25px;          */
/*  border: 1px solid #ddd;       */
/*  position: absolute;           */
/*  top: -15px;                   */
/*  left: 42%;                    */
/*  transition: all 200ms ease-in;*/
/*}                               */

.li.complete .status {
  border-top: 2px solid #66DC71;
}

.li.complete .status .circle {   
  background-color: #66DC71;    
  border: none;                 
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}                               

/*.li.complete .status:before {   */
/*  background-color: #66DC71;    */
/*  border: none;                 */
/*  transition: all 200ms ease-in;*/
/*}                               */

.li.complete .status h4 {
  color: #66DC71;
}

@media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .li {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    display: flex;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .timestamp {
    width: 100px;
  }

  .status:before {
    left: -8%;
    top: 30%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
    <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
      <li class="li complete">
        <div class="timestamp">
          <span class="author">test1</span>
          <span class="date">11<span>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
          <span class="circle"></span>
          <h4> test </h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="li">
        <div class="timestamp">
          <span class="author">test1</span>
          <span class="date">test1<span>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
          <span class="circle"></span>
          <h4> test1 </h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="li">
        <div class="timestamp">
          <span class="author">test1</span>
          <span class="date">test1<span>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
          <span class="circle"></span>
          <h4> test1 </h4>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="li">
        <div class="timestamp">
          <span class="author">test1</span>
          <span class="date">test1<span>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
          <span class="circle"></span>
          <h4> test1 </h4>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the onclick should be called: toggleButton.onclick = function() { toggleComplete()};
Here a reference on how it should be done: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Note that actually it will just toggle (add or remove) the .complete class from the last element retrieved with the document.querySelectorAll() method.